# Cannot convert 'TCHAR*' to 'const char*'

Tags: c++

I don't know why I get these two errors when I run the code. 
error: argument of type 'BOOL (Movement::)(HWND__*, LPARAM)' does not match 'BOOL (*)(HWND__*, LPARAM)'
error: argument of type 'BOOL (Movement::)(HWND__*, LPARAM)' does not match 'BOOL (*)(HWND__*, LPARAM)'

The cpp file is this:

```
#include "movement.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#pragma comment(lib, "user32.lib")

Movement::Movement()
{
    xLoc = 10;
    yLoc = 50;
    while(true){
            windowHandle = NULL;
            EnumWindows(MyEnumProc, 0);

            MoveWindow(windowHandle, getXLoc(), getYLoc(), 1220, 930, false);
            Sleep(5);
        }
}
BOOL CALLBACK Movement::MyEnumProc(HWND hWnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
    TCHAR title[500];
    ZeroMemory(title, sizeof(title));

    //string strTitle;

    GetWindowText(hWnd, title, sizeof(title)/sizeof(title[0]));

    //_tprintf(_T("Found window: %s\n"), title);

    //strTitle += title; // Convert to std::string
    if(_tcsstr(title, _T("Firefox")))
    {
        windowHandle = hWnd;
        return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
int Movement::getXLoc(){
    if(xLoc<70&&yLoc<=30){
        xLoc += 1;
        Sleep(10);
    }else if(yLoc>30){
        xLoc -= 1;
        Sleep(10);
    }
    return xLoc;
}
int Movement::getYLoc(){
    if(yLoc>10&&xLoc<30){
        yLoc -= 1;
        Sleep(10);
    }else if(xLoc>=30&&yLoc<70){
        yLoc += 1;
        Sleep(10);
    }
    return yLoc;
}
```

This is the Header File:

```
#ifndef MOVEMENT_H
#define MOVEMENT_H

#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Movement
{
public:
    Movement();
protected:
    HWND windowHandle;
    BOOL CALLBACK MyEnumProc(HWND hWnd, LPARAM lParam);
    int xLoc;
    int yLoc;
    int getXLoc();
    int getYLoc();
};

#endif // MOVEMENT_H
```

Comment: I don't see how the question title matches the question body. The error isn't related to TCHAR, it's related to passing a class's function as a callback.

Comment: also remember to report where you get the error, since you can't post line number use a comment like : //<-error here!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that `EnumWindows` is expecting a `WNDENUMPROC` parameter which is a typedef for

```
BOOL (*)(HWND, LPARAM);
```

In your code sample `MyEnumProc` has the type

```
BOOL (Movement::*)(HWND, LPARAM);
```

The difference exists because it is an instance method on `Movement`.  To fix this you need to make `MyEnumProc` a static method